# How to record system audio in python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, python-sounddevice

I tried to record audio with this code:

```
import sounddevice
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
fs = 44100
second = 3
file = sounddevice.rec(int(second * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sounddevice.wait()
write('output.wav', fs, file)
```

but it only records output of mic while i want to record system media sound

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems do not offer default output as source to record. You need to do use audio routing tools to archive that.

For example, in MacOS, one could install a tool called Soundflower or some later alternatives. Then on OS level, send all output to that soundflower "device" and then you would be able to record those *after* you select that soundflower device as the source via; https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.5/usage.html#device-selection

On Linux, JACK probably can do the same as MacOS soundflower counterpart. On Windows, no idea...